# Help with understanding a proof on permutations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, permutations

I've come across a theorem in Serge Lang's *Linear Algebra*, which I'm having trouble understanding. First I'll write the proof then indicate which part I do not understand:

**Proposition:** Every permutation of $J_n$ can be expressed a product of transpositions.

**Proof:** We shall prove our assertion by induction on $n$. For $n = 1$, there is nothing to prove. Let $n>1$ and assume the assertion is proved for $n-1$. Let $\sigma$ be a permutation of $J_n$. Let $\sigma(n) = k$. If $k \neq n$ let $\tau$ be the transposition of $J_n$ such that $\tau(k) = n, \tau(n) = k$. If $k=n$, let $\tau = Id$. Then $\tau \sigma$ is a permutation such that $$ \tau \sigma(n) = \tau(k) = n. $$ In other words, $\tau \sigma$ leaves $n$ fixed. We may therefore view $\tau \sigma$ as a permutation of $J_{n-1}$, and by induction, there exist transpositions $\tau_1, \ldots, \tau_s$ of $J_{n-1}$ leaving $n$ fixed, such that $$\tau \sigma = \tau_1 \ldots \tau_s.$$ We can now write $$ \sigma = \tau^{-1} \tau_1 \ldots \tau_s = \tau \tau_1 \ldots \tau_s, $$ thereby proving our proposition. Q.E.D.

I understand everything until he says "$\tau \sigma$ leaves $n$ fixed". What does he mean by that? Also, what is actually the effect of composing $\sigma$ with $\tau$? In this case, we have $\sigma$ that maps $n$ to $k$. If I apply $\tau$ now to $\sigma$, does this just mean that $n$ and $k$ have swapped positions under the image of $\tau \sigma$?

Also, I'm not sure why $\tau \sigma$ can be viewed as a permutation of $J_{n-1}$ instead of $J_n$.

Comment: $\sigma$ sends $n$ to $k$ and $\tau$ sends $k$ to $n$, so if you do $\sigma$ followed by $\tau$ it sends $n$ to $k$ and then back to $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By ‘$\tau\sigma$ leaves $n$ fixed’ he means simply that $(\tau\sigma)(n)=n$. Since $\sigma(n)=k$, and $\tau(k)=n$, this is clear: the composite function $\tau\sigma$ has $n$ as a fixed point. We don’t know what it does to $k$, since we don’t know what $\sigma(k)$ is.

Because $\tau\sigma$ does not move $n$, it must permute the numbers $1$ through $n-1$ amongst themselves. In other words, if we restrict the function $\tau\sigma$ to the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, we get a permutation of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$: nothing gets sent out of the set (i.e., to $n$), because the $\tau\sigma$ sends $n$ to $n$.

Comment: I see, thanks. OK, I understand now that $\tau \sigma$ can be seen as a permutation of $J_{n-1}$. But how did he deduce from this the fact that $\tau \sigma = \tau_1 \ldots \tau_s$ ?

Comment: @Kamil: This is a proof by induction on $n$, so he’s assuming that every permutation of $J_{n-1}$ can be written as a product of transpositions and using that to prove that the same is true of every permutation of $J_n$. In other words, his induction hypothesis tells him that $\tau\sigma$, being essentially a permutation of $J_{n-1}$, is a product of transpositions.